# Allow microphone and webcam redirection via RDP on Windows Server 2016 host

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

I have Amazon WorkSpaces - running Windows Server 2016 version 1607. I cannot change the OS.

I can connect via RDP already, but I'd like to make my local microphone and webcam available to the remote machine as well. Audio playback and smart card readers connect just fine.

I've noticed that if I install the *Remote Desktop Services* role via Server Manager, with the *Remote Desktop Session Host* service enabled (and nothing else) it makes the microphone work, but not the webcam. I don't even need to configure anything once I install that service.

But... in addition I also get pestered about licensing. Removing this service makes the microphone stop working again. And when the grace period expires I'm not let into my machine anymore for I don't have a license server...

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE: This answer which doesn't address the Remote Desktop Services licensing issue.*

As I was investigating this, I noticed the following:

- Windows 10 Pro works just fine
- Windows Server 2019 supports webcam transport too, as long as I install the RDS service, with the same licensing issue I mentioned
- Windows 10 Pro and Windows Server 2019 have a Group Policy entry that Windows Server 2016 does not:

> **Location:**
>
> - Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Device and Resource Redirection
>
> **Name:**
>
> - Do not allow video capture redirection
>
> **Requirements:**
>
> At least Windows Server 2016, Windows 10 Version 1803
>
> **Description:**
>
> This policy setting lets you control the redirection of video capture devices to the remote computer in a Remote Desktop Services session.
>
> By default, Remote Desktop Services allows redirection of video capture devices.
>
> If you enable this policy setting, users cannot redirect their video capture devices to the remote computer.
>
> If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, users can redirect their video capture devices to the remote computer. Users can use the More option on the Local Resources tab of Remote Desktop Connection to choose the video capture devices to redirect to the remote computer.

The description seems to hint that I need version 1803 of Windows Server 2016 for this to work.

The Internet says 1803 is a core-only release (no GUI), and one cannot update to it from 1607.

I do not know what Windows 10 has already that Windows Server does not until RDS Session Host is installed.